# Delete Row From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the section of code below to create a table which correctly list records pertinent to the `current user`.

```
/* display row for each user */ 


echo "<tr>\n"; 
$theID = $row['locationid']; 
echo " <td style='text-align: Center'>{$row['locationname']}</td>\n";
echo " <td style='text-align: Left'>{$row['returnedaddress']}</td>\n"; 
echo " <td style='text-align: Center'>{$row['totalfinds']}</td>\n"; 
echo " <form action= locationsaction.php  method= 'post'><input type='hidden' name='lid' value=$theID/>                                             <td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Details'/></td>
<td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Images'/></td>
<td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Add Finds'/></td>
<td><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'View Finds'/></td>
<td><input type= 'submit' name = 'type' value= 'Delete'/></td></form>\n";
```

At the end of each table row there are a selection of buttons which via `locatiosnaction.php` shown below , navigate the user to other pages, all linked back to the main table record.

**'locationsaction.php'**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['lid'] = $_POST['lid'];
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $urls = array(
        'Details' => 'viewlocation.php',
        'Add Finds' => 'addfinds.php',
        'Images' => 'addimages.php',
        'View Finds' => 'locationfinds.php',
        'Delete' => 'deletelocation.php'
    );
    $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

The problem I'm having revolves around the deletion of the record. This is the query I'm using:

**'deletelocation.php'**

```
<?php

    $lid = $_SESSION['lid'];
            $query = "DELETE FROM detectinglocations WHERE locationid='$lid'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

?>
```

The functionality of the button works fine, as it takes the user to the deletelocation.php script, but it's not deleting the record.

I've been using several scripts as reference and I'd thought I'd followed them correctly, but clearly not.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the SQL you're generating, and running it straight in the database?

Comment: write a `echo mysql_error();` to your deletelocation.php please and post your output

Comment: have you tried deleting this id? `'or 1=1`

Comment: Is this the whole delete script? You don't actually connect to the database via mysql_connect(). Simple error checking via `echo mysql_error()` will reveal this.

Comment: It's becoming so incredibly repetitive to post about being vulnerable to sql injections it seems people just don't care anymore to post that. Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58216/why-isnt-protection-against-sql-injection-a-high-priority

Comment: First of all, you're exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks.  You'll want to do some input checking on `$_POST['lid']` before using it for _anything_, especially for a database query.  Also take a look at the mysqli functions to replace the mysql functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  As for why your code isn't deleting any rows... What are the run-time values?  At least do _some_ debugging.  What does `$query` ultimately contain when it's executed against the database?  Was the ID stored in the session?  Was it posted to the first page at all? At *what point* does this fail?

Comment: @Michael, come on! Who needs authentication, input validation or even database connection?

Comment: All, I'm very sorry to have upset you. I'd like to point out that I do have 'Input validation', 'authentication' and 'database connection'. I hadn't appreciated that you needed to see that and I didn't want to post a whole page of script. Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `session_start();` at the beginning of `deletelocation.php`.

You have to call this on every page, that wants to use the session.

So in your case `$_SESSION['lid']` is not resolvable, which will invalidate your SQL query.

[PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session or **resumes the current one** ...

Comment: Hi @ Sirko, thank you for taking the time to send a solution. I'm very new to programming in PHP, so your help is greatly appreciated. Kind regards